# Keep custom error message only when using dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling, summary

I use `dplyr` a lot in some package's internals, but I'm struggling with error handling.

In one function (`bar()`), I have to use another function (`foo()`) inside a `summarise()` call, with an argument to choose the function to apply. Users choose this summary function in the main function of the package.

However, this function should obviously return a single value, otherwise the `summarise()` call will fail.

Therefore, the function `foo()` checks the length of the returned value and raises an error if it is incorrect.

This is totally hidden from the end-user and should remain so.

**Here comes the problem**: this error is captured by `summarise()`, so users don't see right ahead that they made a mistake. The actual message is lost among some other messages, which are irrelevant in this case.

Is there a way to make this `stop()` call independent from `summarise()`?

#### Reproducible example

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
foo = function(x, fun){
    rtn=fun(x)
    if(length(rtn)>1)
        stop("Summary functions should return a single value")
    rtn
}

bar = function(fun){
    iris %>% 
        group_by(Species) %>% 
        summarise(x=foo(Sepal.Length, fun))
}

foobar = function(fun){ #main function of the package
    bar(fun)
}
foobar(mean)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Species        x
#>   <fct>      <dbl>
#> 1 setosa      5.01
#> 2 versicolor  5.94
#> 3 virginica   6.59
foobar(fivenum)
#> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `x`.
#> x Summary functions should return a single value
#> i Input `x` is `foo(Sepal.Length, fun)`.
#> i The error occurred in group 1: Species = "setosa".
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Here, the expected output would have been simply:

```r
foobar(fivenum)
#> Error: Summary functions should return a single value
```

NB: Please keep in mind that this is a simplified version of the actual code. For those who are curious, you can find the code [here](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/crosstable/blob/03af6cf5a2a183ae8b680e5752c8377fd8f319e7/R/summarize_numeric.R). The function `summarize_numeric_single()` will soon check that `length(v)!=length(funs)`.

Comment: So you mean when you do `foobar(fivenum)` you should only get `Summary functions should return a single value` and not the other messages?

Comment: @RonakShah yes, exactly. The problem lies with the `fun` argument, not with `summarise()`.